# Access login session variables like username

Tags: java, javascript

On launch of our application, it is navigated to LDAP for validation purpose. After successful validation it navigates to home page of our application. I need to make use of the username that logged in for doing some operations on home page based on the login user.
When I look at the username input text field through Firebug, it is like below.

```
<input type="text" tabindex="2/" value="" maxlength="40" title=" Please enter a Username " name="loginusername" id="login_username">
```

Please help me in retrieving the username through javascript or java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in JavaScript

```
var name= document.getElementsByName('loginusername')[0].value; //fetching value of input element by name
```

or this

```
var name=document.getElementById('login_username').value; //fetching value of input element by id
```

Comment: Im getting below error when I try to use above code snippet.           Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: @sircapsalot: No i'm trying to get the value of input type.

Comment: then you're doing it wrong. `document.getElementsByName('loginusername')[0].value` is what you want, since getElementsByName() will return an array of elements.

Comment: @sircapsalot : Okies yeah, i was looking at id part, thanks mate :) updated the answer

Comment: 1)when I use getElementsByClassName, getting below error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined 
2)when getElementById is used getting the error below. 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: These errors indicate that there is no element on your page with given name or id, share your html code not firebug to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually that login HTML is not part of our application. Application is navigated to this LDAP for validating the user and once successfully validated, navigates back to my application home page.

Comment: try this if it works
`var name=document.getElementById('username').value; alert(name);`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this.

```
var user = $('#login_username').val();
alert(user);
```

if you have to use pure javascript then you can do it by this way

```
var user = document.getElementById('login_username').value; 
alert(user);
```

Comment: Where did you see `jQuery` tagged??

Comment: I am restricted to use pure javascript but not jquery.

Comment: If you have to use pure js then you can use var user = document.getElementById('login_username').value; alert(user);

Comment: The below error being thrown
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @user1611498 jQuery *is* "pure javascript"